# Knockout JS [Object object] pulling properties

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an object in my JS sliced from an array:

```
self.deploysToDevId = ko.computed(function() {
  var deployToDev = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.builds(), function(build) {
    return build.buildType() == 'Deploy to Development';
  }, self);
  var deployToDevID = deployToDev.slice(0,1).id
  return deployToDevID;
});
```

This object is originally from an array called builds and is a build object. However, I am trying to get a property, the "id" of the build which is a property of build, and I want to be able to store this and return this as an object, however when I do the data-bind prints the text [Object object]

```
self.getIdOfMostRecentDeploy  = ko.computed(function() {
  var idOfMostRecentDeploy = (self.deploysToDevId().id);
  return idOfMostRecentDeploy;
});
```

This should store the id of the object as "idOfMostRecentDeploy" but it is not doing so.

```
      self.deploysToDevId = ko.computed(function() {
    var deployToDev = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.builds(), function(build) {
        return build.buildType() == 'Deploy to Development';
        }, 
        self);
        var deployToDevID = deployToDev[0];
        return deployToDevID;
});
```

This is another way I have tried, this time trying to take the first object in the array and assign its id to a variable. although, I still just get [Object object]

Comment: Can you show an example of your deployToDev data structure?

Comment: Is `.id` perhaps an `observable` or `computed`? Based on the output, it's an object of some sort. I also see in `deploysToDevId` you're returning an `id` property of a build (I assume you're expecting a string?), but `getIdOfMostRecentDeploy` is accessing an `id` property of that computed. So does the build ID have an `id` property of its own? We really need to see the structure of the source data to help.

Comment: Or an example of what `self.builds` contains will help.

Comment: .id is an observable. There are numerous properties associated with a build, and Id is one of them. The id is a String, When in the html, I am able to use a foreach through builds and use data-binds to get the id, but I am unable to get the id as a single variable. The build id does not have an id, no. The id is for the build.

Comment: You need to show your view and your data model. Best if you reproduce it as a working sample (use the snippet feature of the editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this:

```
self.deploysToDevId = ko.computed(function() {
  var deployToDev = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.builds(), function(build) {
    return build.buildType() == 'Deploy to Development';
  }, self);
  var deployToDevID = deployToDev.slice(0,1).id
  return deployToDevID;
});
```

you are creating a computed that will contain just the `id` of the `deployToDev` object, which I presume is an observable (that is, a javascript function you need to eval to get the value)

Then, when you try to access it using:

```
(self.deploysToDevId().id)
```

this is returning basically nothing, because the "id" you are looking for is in the computed itself, `self.deploysToDevId()`, not in any inner id property

EDIT:

I have created this fiddle that may help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/r88zkn11/

in you case the only difference is that the object instead if having `id` and `buildType` as string objects, they are functions, so if you have to use them you have to evaluate them (use `buildType()` instead of `buildType`)

Comment: Is there any way I could get the Id of the object and store it as a variable?

Comment: Please look if the response is good enough now, if not do not hesitate on asking again

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var deployToDevID = deployToDev.slice(0,1).id;
```

You are saying: give me an array one element long, and take the `id` property of that array. The array doesn't have an `id` property. Instead, you should be indexing the first element:

```
var deployToDevID = deployToDev[0].id;
```

Then, as JulioCT notes, the computed will return the id. It doesn't have an id member, it's just the id.

In your last example, you take the first element but *don't* take its `id` property, so naming it `deployToDevID` is misleading. Take the `id` of it as I suggest above, and then use `deployToDevID` anywhere you want to use that id.

Comment: is there any way that I can get the inner id which is held within the deployToDev object within the array?

Comment: Yes, you just need to keep track of what you are actually storing in the variables. In your last example, you call your variable `deployToDevID`, but you store a build element (which does have an `id` element). So you'd do `deployToDevID.id` for that.